# How to change the background color of title section of html report

Tags: r, r-markdown, background-color, page-title

I'm creating an interactive HTML document using R markdown and I cannot figure out how to add background color only to the title section. I've seen posts about how to change the background color of different chunks, but I want to apply color only to where the title appears. I was using the html pretty package originally that did this for me but it wasn't compatible with some features I needed to add into the report so now I have to figure out a way to add the color back in manually.

This is what it currently looks like:

[image: What it looks like, currently]

and I want it to look like this:

[image: What I want it to look like]

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use your own CSS code to alter the design.

1. Open your document in a browser and right click on the title.
   Select *Inspect Element* to identify it. In your case we want to alter `#header` and the containing `h1` with class `.title`.
2. Alter the elements! For example:

   ```
   <style> 
     #header { 
       background: #2274cc; /* Old browsers */
       background: -moz-linear-gradient(left, #2274cc 0%, #26c5d3 36%, #61bf61 100%); /* FF3.6-15 */
       background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #2274cc 0%,#26c5d3 36%,#61bf61 100%); /* Chrome10-25,Safari5.1-6 */
       background: linear-gradient(to right, #2274cc 0%,#26c5d3 36%,#61bf61 100%); /* W3C, IE10+, FF16+, Chrome26+,  Opera12+, Safari7+ */
       filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#2274cc', endColorstr='#61bf61',GradientType=1 ); /* IE6-9 */
       color: white;
       height: 100px;
       display:flex;
       align-items: center;
       justify-content: center;
     }

     h1.title {
       margin: auto;
     }
   </style>
   ```

This code goes into your rmarkdown document without any wrapping. You can put it right underneath the YAML header or even include it by using an extern `.css` file (check out the YAML option to include stylesheets).

The code for the background gradient can easily be generated by using an online tool like http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/.

A good reference for how to use CSS is https://www.w3schools.com/Css/.

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! For some reason the flex display option isn't working so I cannot currently vertically align the text, but everything else looks great ^_^